# Facebook login within Flash without popup or redirect?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

Does anybody know how to handle a Facebook login from within Flash using REST API/FB Connect, without the popup or redirect?

It doesnt seem very possible as the login method seems to force the popup.

Might it be possible by modding the code to have it load in an unseen iframe (i.e. navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=....yadayadayada....&method=permissions.request"),"iframe");) and then sending an external interface call to javascript telling it to handle the subsequent DOM elements (login email and password fields and allow button) based on interactions in Flash? I'm open to creative suggestions... however crazy or complicated they may be.

Answer (score 1):

use this to make a call to the FB REST-API

```
//Make a variables variable
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables;

//set information that is to be POSTed to fb
vars.user = username;
vars.pass = pass;

//connect to facebook api
var Request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("fbapiurlhere");
Request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

//add variables
Request.data = vars;

//create a URL loader
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (Request);

//specify what the returned data is
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

//send it off
loader.load(Request);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! :-)

I have an additional couple questions if you could help.

Would this method provide the API the needed login info to go about acquiring a session and posting to a wall? Also how might you do this? Something like? 

session=new FacebookSessionUtil(API_KEY, SECRET_KEY, loaderInfo); 
var post:PublishPost = new PublishPost( message );
var call:FacebookCall = session.facebook.post( post );

?


The goal here is I'm trying to post to a user wall if the user provides my flash app with their username and pass. Pardon my ignorance in these matters.

Comment: I dont use the Facebook API very often, adobe just developed a facebook api class http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ check it out, it should be what your looking for, happy programming

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do login without a popup or redirect. If you're using the [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you can do a background ping using [FB.getLoginStatus()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) which will return the user session **if they have already authorized your application**.